# REST - when I access a resource should it contain all its sub resources or should they be fetched in a new request?

Tags: rest

ie. my resource has a list of user's associated with it should I:

1. return the `resource` object containing all associated `user` objects embedding in it
2. return the `resource` object with a list of user ids then request for the `user` objects separately
3. return the `resource` object, make a request for the resource's user ids (from the resource_and_user pivot table) then request for the `user` objects in a third request

Do any of these options violate REST?

Answer (score 0):

The use case should be what drives the decision.

If the use case was to get a dump of all `user` objects for data transfer then a simple `api/user` should return a list of user objects. Option `1`

If the use case was to provide some hierarchy with the user like a user could have many blog posts then you might want number `2` so you'd do `api/user` to get a list of users and then do `api/user/{userId}/blogPost` to get all the blogposts related to the user with that id.

Option 3 seems a bit over kill.